# Sql Server Trigger between 2 databases 

Tags: triggers

I have 2 databases. One, named Test, has a table named Vehicles. Another, named Test2 has a table named Clients.

When I insert a new record on the Vehicles table in Test, I need to update the NumVehicles field on the Clients table in Test2.

Is this possible using triggers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need something like

```
USE Test;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER afterVehicleInsert ON Vehicles AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN 
  IF @@rowcount = 0 RETURN;

  UPDATE Test2.[schema_name(default schema is dbo)].Clients 
  SET NumVehicles = NumVehicles +1 -- or whatever it should be
  FROM Test2.[schema_name(default schema is dbo)].Clients c
  INNER JOIN inserted i ON ([your join condition])
END;  
GO
```

The only difference between updating the table in current and another db is that you need to refer a "remote" table using [db_name].[schema_name].[table_name]

Answer (score 0):

This is working code is given below

```
USE BioStar;
    GO 
    CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsertnew ON [dbo].[TB_EVENT_LOG] 
    FOR INSERT
    AS
        declare @nDateTime int;
        declare @nReaderIdn int;
        declare @nEventIdn int;
        declare @nUserID int;
        declare @nIsLog smallint;
        declare @nTNAEvent smallint;
        declare @nIsUseTA smallint;
        declare @nType smallint;


        select @nDateTime=i.nDateTime from inserted i;  
        select @nDateTime=i.nReaderIdn from inserted i; 
        select @nEventIdn=i.nEventIdn from inserted i;  
        select @nUserID=i.nUserID from inserted i;

        select @nIsLog=i.nIsLog from inserted i;    
        select @nTNAEvent=i.nTNAEvent from inserted i;  
        select @nIsUseTA=i.nIsUseTA from inserted i;    
        select @nType=i.nType from inserted i;
        insert into [HRM].dbo.Device_Data
               (nDateTime,nReaderIdn,nEventIdn,nUserID,nIsLog,nTNAEvent,nIsUseTA,nType) 
        values(@nDateTime,@nDateTime,@nEventIdn,@nUserID,@nIsLog,@nTNAEvent,@nIsUseTA,@nType);


        --set @audit_action='Inserted Record -- After Insert Trigger.';
            PRINT 'AFTER DELETE TRIGGER fired.'
    GO
```