# IN SQL DATA TRANSFER Between To different databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For example, in `Test12` DB I have two tables

Table 1: `Emp_Details`:

```
Emp_ID int
[Emp_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
```

Table 2: `salary`:

```
[Sal_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Salary] [varchar](50) NULL,
```

I want to update and insert automatically (when they are modified) `Emp_Name` from `Emp_Details` table and `Salary` from `Salary` table

To another Database, `Test22`, which has a table `DepTable`:

```
Dep_ID [int] 
Dep_Name  varchar(50) NULL,
Emp_Name varchar(50) NULL,  
Salary1  varchar(50) NULL,
```

Respectively, if you have any ideas, please help me.

Comment: Are you asking for some kind of synchronization/replication?

Comment: You can write triggers, you can use change data capture, etc. Please write some more information and please tell why you want to do that - i am pretty sure that you should do that in the way you want right now

Comment: I am not sure why you want to do this as that structure is breaking normalization. That means it will be difficult to properly maintain over time, so it is best not to use that structure if you have any choice about it.  If you have control over this design, fix it now

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to a table in another database using a three-part identifier: `<db>.<schema>.<table>`.  So you can specify:

```
SELECT * FROM Test12.dbo.Emp_Details
```

or:

```
INSERT INTO Test22.dbo.Dep_ID ...
```

If they're on different servers or in different instances of the same server, you should look into a [Linked server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279(v=sql.110).aspx) which lets you use a four-part identifier: `<linked_server_name>.<db>.<schema>.<table>`.

To do it automatically, you could use a [trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652286/sql-server-trigger-between-2-databases) or a task with SQL Agent that runs periodically, or an SSIS package.