# Connect two tables from different databases on same server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to connect two tables from different databases on the same SQL Server 2008 R2 instance? When one is being updated or inserted into, the other table should be updated automatically.

Example:

- `Table 1` from Customer database
- `Table 2` from Supplier database

When something is inserted into `Table 1`, at the same time `Table 2` should be updated with same data of `Table 1`.

Comment: yes. please ask a more specific question.

Comment: Please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652286/sql-server-trigger-between-2-databases) to trigger for two database objects

Comment: i am a beginner  will you help me to do this.|

Answer (score 2):

One way is to create a [`SYNONYM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql) for `Customer.dbo.Table1` in the `Supplier` database. You can then query the synonym as though it were in the `Supplier` database.

Suppose you have the `Customer` database with `Table1` and the `Supplier` database with `Table2`. Suppose both tables are in the `dbo` schema. You can then test the following in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS):

```
USE Supplier; -- Tell SSMS to switch to the Supplier database

CREATE SYNONYM Table1 FOR Customer.dbo.Table1; -- this creates a synonym permanently in the Supplier database; you only need to execute this once

SELECT * FROM Table1; -- select all from Customer.dbo.Table1, from within the context of database Supplier
```

This way there is no need for `TRIGGER`s and the corresponding overhead (you would need 3 `TRIGGER`s to keep the tables in sync).

Answer (score 0):

```
USE Customer
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Table1_AI
   ON dbo.Table1
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
        RETURN;

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE t2
        SET ColumnX = i.ColumnX, ColumnY = i.ColumnY
        FROM Supplier.dbo.Table2 t2
        INNER JOIN inserted i on i.id = t2.id;
END
GO
```

Replace `ColumnX = i.ColumnX, ColumnY = i.ColumnY` and `i.id = t2.id` considering your logic.

Comment: Now,question is what is UPDATE t2

Comment: t2 is alias for table Supplier.dbo.Table2

Comment: sorry this code will not wok on different database.this is for just on same database.

Comment: i want to insert one table data into an other table.by using trigger.

Comment: sorry, i want to insert one table into another on different database.

Comment: @Md.DidarulIslam Have you at least tried it? You say *will* not work as though you know but haven't tried. Did you at least try?

Comment: like one database name is Biolite an other is HRM in same server .now i want to insert table data from biolite to HRM.

Comment: @RuslanK. This is one of the triggers that would be needed. Triggers for UPDATE/DELETE would also be needed to fully link both tables. Also, there is very little context you provide in the answer. Some minimal context would be good here.

Comment: @TT. you are right, but question contains too little information

Comment: @Ruslank forget everything,now what i want is trigger for insert data from one to another table . 
Ex: Database name is Biolite and table name is Event_Log 
an other one is HRM table name is From_Device
 now help me to do. Select from Event_Log and INSERT INTO From_Device