# Merge 2 tables with different databases

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Consider Database 1 & Database 2 having a single table each **Table 1** & **Table 2**

How is it possible to update table 1 inserting/updating/deleting any change that happens to Table 2?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Please tag your DBMS (SQL server, MySQL, Oracle) and the version.

Comment: Are they on the same server?

Comment: @Shawn, no they are on separate servers.

Comment: If they are on different servers, I believe you'll have to set up a trusted relationship between the two for them to be able to talk to each other. Then it should just be a simple matter of running an UPDATE script on database1 that refers to <server2>.Database2.<schema>.Table2.  EDIT: Missed the part about updating changes. I was going on a 1-time change idea. Yes, cross db trigger would probably be best.

Comment: Look into Federated Storage Engine. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-storage-engine.html

Comment: Helpful! Thanks @Shawn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do a cross database trigger.

If you're using SQL server you can read here: 
[Sql Server Trigger between 2 databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652286/sql-server-trigger-between-2-databases)

If you're using Mysql you can read here: 
[Cross database trigger in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421699/cross-database-trigger-in-mysql)

Comment: Cross Database Trigger is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps create a `view` showing both tables?

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT * FROM db1.Table1, db2.Table2
```

Any change happening at any of the tables will be shown on the view, I hope it's what you wanted~

Comment: Creating a view will help me see the difference between each table, however I am looking for a solution to have a Table 1 receive all the changes done remotely on Table 2.